# PHP: Edit href in <a> link

Tags: php, wordpress, href

I want to edit the URL to a specific URL as I can't find the user meta in WordPress nor in the phpMyAdmin in the cPanel.

I want to change this:

```
if(get_user_meta( $user_id, 'googleplus', $single) !=""){
  echo "<br/><a class='author-link g' title='Follow on Google+' href=".get_user_meta( $user_id, googleplus', $single )." target='_blank'>Google+</a>";
  }
```

To:

```
if(get_user_meta( $user_id, 'googleplus', $single) !=""){
  echo "<br/><a class='author-link g' title='Follow on Google+' href="https://example.com" target='_blank'>Google+</a>";
  }
```

And the error is:

```
syntax error, unexpected 'https' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'
```

I have tried:

```
href="<?php echo "http://www.example.com"; ?>"
```

```
href="https:\/\/www.example.com"
```

```
href="https://www.example.com"
```

Would appreciate any advice as I have zero knowledge in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
 echo "<br/><a class='author-link g' title='Follow on Google+' href="https://example.com" target='_blank'>Google+</a>";
```

to

```
 echo '<br/><a class="author-link g" title="Follow on Google+" href="https://example.com" target="_blank">Google+</a>';
```

Comment: tnx, accept the answer.

Comment: Sure, but it allows me to accept it in 6 more minutes. Will do so then. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in using [single quoted](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) and [double quoted](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) 
in your code 
change **"example.com"**  to **'example.com'**
OR use it like this way **\"example.com\"** to escape double quoted

The finnal right code will be

```
if(get_user_meta( $user_id, 'googleplus', $single) !=""){
  echo "<br/><a class='author-link g' title='Follow on Google+' href='https://example.com' target='_blank'>Google+</a>";
  }
```